# Which Path should I use in my website? Related path absolute path?

Tags: javascript, html, web, path

I am building website for my client. I was wondering which path should I use for my website? which path is more secure? also correct me if I am totally wrong or if you have other reason for safety concerns for website! Thanks in advance.

For example...

```
<script src="https://example.com/admin/js/myjavascript.js"></script>
or
<script src="/js/myjavascript.js"></script>

<img src="https://swadtiffin.ca/wp-content/uploads/myimg.jpg" alt="Loading...!">
or
<img src="/wp-content/uploads/myimg.jpg" alt="Loading...!">

$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/wp-content/themes/astra-child/php/get_all_food_combos.php',
  data: $.param({ 'data': "test" }),
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
  }).then(function (resp) {
  console.log(resp.data); //all items
  });
  }, function (error) {
     console.log(error);
  });

or

$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://example.com/wp-content/themes/astra-child/php/get_combos.php',
  data: $.param({ 'data': "test" }),
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
  }).then(function (resp) {
  console.log(resp.data); //all items
  });
  }, function (error) {
     console.log(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Both of your way are OK. Secure is not different. But use in different scenario.

- If you prefix  your service with URL.  `(https://example.com/wp-content/...php)` that mean you can only get data from this URL. And if you have service run in another website you must do in this way.
- If you not prefix it will automatically use service in your local path.

Answer (score 1):

As Anukul mentioned in this case both are okay.

The URI Paths generally do not effect the security of a an application. It is a matter of preference and following standards.

There are a couple of things to consider when determining paths though:

1. Is there sensitive data?

   If so don't use path parameters or query
       parameters to send this sensitive data. If possible use a request
       payload in a POST with SSL/TLS.
2. GET methods are generally logged in server logs.

   Would this be okay in this circumstance with the parameters?